# get image from url and resize while keeping quality of image

Tags: php, image

using the following function to resize image.

```html
<?php
function resize($get_width, $get_height, $image_url){
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_url);
  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($get_width, $get_height);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_url);
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image_url, 0, 0, 0, 0, $get_width, $get_height, $width, $height);
  imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
}
?>
```

**PROBLEM**

Image is losing quality while resizing.

**Example**

Image resized using css

[image]

Image Resized Using Function Above

[image]

**What I Need**

is the quality like the first image but with using a php function not css.

Comment: Are you making the image larger or smaller

Comment: @RiggsFolly making it smaller

Comment: Then are you changing the shape?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, i am just getting an image of size 640x480 and resizing it to multiple smaller sizes such as 187x140 and 471x314

Comment: Those new measurements are not the same scale as the original. That will cause distortion

Comment: @RiggsFolly you mean i should keep the aspect ratio same as of original image?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean